# Can't write to Linux NFS share from OSX client

Tags: linux, mac-osx, nfs

I'm trying to connect to an NFS drive shared from my Debian Squeeze box from my OSX 10.6 laptop, and try as I might I can't get it to let me write to the disk from the mac. I have the following in /etc/exports:

```
/mnt/usbdrive 192.168.1.0/24(rw,insecure,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

making all requests come from UID/GID 1000/1000, my user, who owns the whole drive. However, when I mount the drive on the Mac, everything is owned by 1000/1000 as well, so I can never write to the disk:

```
~> ls -la /Volumes/USBDrive/
drwxr-xr-x  6 1000  1000    4096  5 Sep 19:31 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 4 root  admin    170  6 Sep 22:41 ..
drwx------  2 1000  1000   16384 28 Aug 21:24 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000  1000    4096 29 Aug 15:35 music
```

I've seen a few other people having this problem, but the only solution I've seen is to chmod the whole disk 777, which I'd rather avoid. Unfortunately I can't use nfs-user-server on my system so I can't use UID/GID mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than assign all files to uid 1000, assign all files to your uid on the Mac (run `id -u` in a terminal to see your uid). While you're at it, do the same for the gid (`id -g`).

Answer (score 2):

this is what worked for me on MacOS 11.1 BigSur (nfs client), running Ubuntu 20.04 inside VirtualBox VM, using the 'host-only' network for direct connection to the vm. Presumably this would work between two physical machines.

*** note the vm has no firewall enabled because it is a host-only vm running inside my mac. Obviously you need to have ports open on the firewall on the server normally for this.

Macbook (client) is 192.168.56.1
Ubuntu VM (server) is 192.168.56.11

Edit `/etc/exports` on server:

```
/home/don     192.168.56.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,all_squash)
```

*** remember to run `exportfs -a` after editing the `/etc/exports` file, before running `mount` over on the mac client.

** id 1000 and gid 1000 is the 'don' user on the ubuntu vm

On the mac:

```
sudo mount -o resvport,rw -t nfs 192.168.56.11:/home/don /Users/don/ubuntudevnfs
```

and

```
sudo umount -t nfs /Users/don/ubuntudevnfs
```

`resvport` on the mac (client) side negates the need for `insecure` on the server side export.

UID/GID 1000 is the 'don' user on the server, as seen from the mac client:
[sample text file created on mac client terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhDxV.jpg)

How it looks on the server:
[view of /home/don via ssh into the ubuntu vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sHs1.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as is, with a Debian 10.9 server and a MacOS 10.14 Mojave client.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: Create a group with the same group id on both platforms and make the user on both platforms a member of it, and then change the anongid parameter to this group id.